# What does the rt(a,b) function do in R?

Tags: r

I can't seem to find what this does online. Does is create a random distribution?

Comment: There is no statistical question here so I've voted to migrate to stackoverflow. For future reference, you can also type `help(rt)` or `?rt` which takes you to the help page for the function `rt`, which should answer your question completely.

Answer (score 3):

The `rt` function takes three parameters and returns random draws from the specified $t$ distribution: `n` - the number of observations, `df` - the degrees of freedom, and `ncp` - the non-centrality parameter. So `rt(a,b)` returns `a` random draws from a $t$ distribution centered at $0$ with `b` degrees of freedom.

Comment: What happened if I used a large b value? Is it like normal distribution in this case?

Comment: Yes. You can see this pretty easily by plotting the `t` density with varying degrees of freedom against the normal density. (in r)

    x <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
    n_x <- dnorm(x) 
    plot(n_x ~ x, type = 'l', col = 'red')
    for (d in c(1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20)) {
      t_x <- dt(x, d)
      lines(t_x ~ x)
    }